# c++ equivlent to c# 9.0 New() with deduce type

Tags: c++, new-operator

C# 9+ knows to deduce the type of RHS from LHS, just call `New` with the correct parameters and have your object. No need to repeat lengthy types, and the type is always correct

```
List<int> ints = New(capacity: 10_000);
```

Can the same DRY `new` be done in c++ ?

I have something similar using "safe" new and delete that take the target as argument and deduce type etc using templates, but it is a bit less readable than just `my_var = new(arg1, arg2, arg3)`

Please note this is a question about how to do `a = new(1,2,3)` , like C#, and not about now to create new objects in c++ which make look something like  `list<vector<toupel<int,float,char>>>*a = new list<vector<toupel<int,float,char>>>()`
' sometimes wrapper with `shared_ptr` and co.

[new-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator)

Comment: It is a question about C# syntax feature which saves repetitions, and how to do the same with C++.

Comment: Since C++11, the language has had [`auto`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) for deduced type.

Comment: Yes, auto would be nice, something like `a = new auto(10)` , unfortunately i don't think it works..

Comment: Try `auto a = new int[10_000];`, which does work.

Comment: In the example `a = new auto(10)`, what is supposed to be created? An `int` value initialized to `10`? A `std::vector<int>` with a single element `10`? A `std::vector<some_other_type>` with with `10` default-constructed elements? Some other object that can be created from the integer value `10`? Without specifying type at least once, there's just too much ambiguity. Even in the C# case the type is specified once.

Comment: And in C++ `new` isn't needed (and actively discouraged in most situations) for creations of values and objects. Assuming that by `a = new auto(10);` you really meant `int a = 10;` your variant is even much more verbose.

Comment: In C#:
complex<type<with,specific>,arguments> a;
a = New(1,2,3) ; will deduce the type of a and create a new object.

Answer (score 8):

First of all you should seldom use explicit memory management in modern C++. Use smart pointers like [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) with ownership semantics.

As for your problem, you can do it in roughly the same way, but kind of opposite instead: Auto-deduction of the type in the declaration, and specify the type in the `new` expression:

```
auto* my_pointer = new MyClass<template_type>(arguments, to, constructor);
```

Or using unique pointers:

```
auto my_unique_pointer = std::make_unique<MyClass<template_type>>(arguments, to, constructor);
```

---

As for the subject of containers, you should almost never make pointers to containers. If you need a container, just create an instance of it:

```
std::vector<int> v1(10000);  // Create a vector of 10000 integers
```

Comment: @user1656671 Regarding the example object creation shown in the question, the example using `std::vector` is almost an exact equivalent using the "default" container of C++. In C++ there's no need for `new` or `New` or similar to create an object, so there's just no repetition of types.

Comment: It is a question about C# syntax feature which saves repetitions, and how to do the same with C++ without repeating the type explicitly.

Comment: @user1656671 And in none of my examples are there any repetition of types.

Comment: @user1656671 Are you perhaps thinking about the `auto` keyword? That's needed, you can't define (auto-deducing) variables without it, that's just not how C++ is specified to work.

Comment: Unfortunately I must have phrased the question badly as the answers do not answer it..

in C# you can write some<complex<type>>a;

than later in the code:

a = New(1,2,3)

no repetition of the type.

Please check out the link in the question and the example below.

Comment: @user1656671 • What you are doing in C#9+ is considered bad practice in modern C++.  In part, because C# is a managed language, and C++ is an unmanaged language... so what is best practices in C# (promiscuous ownership of references; IDisposable) are terrible practices in C++ (because they'll lead to memory leaks and poor/muddled ownership).  When in Rome, do as the Romans do.  I suggest not making C++ be like C#, and vice versa.

Comment: @user1656671 Ah, you mean to *reassign* a new object to an already existing object? Like `some_vector = std::vector<int>(10000);`? Then you can't do it without repeating the type in C++. While some statements might seem similar between C++ and C#, you have to remember that they are ultimately two *very* different languages. It's like French and Spanish, both are romance languages (common root in vulgar Latin) but still two completely different languages.

Comment: @Eljay
All these unique_ptr, shared_ptr and various siblings are just degenerate cousins or real GC. So having some more syntactic sugar to mimic some good stuff from C#9 is not that bad idea..

Comment: @user1656671 • C++ does not have GC.  I'm one of the biggest C# fans (since I worked on C# and WPF/XAML for years when I was at Microsoft), but the good stuff from C# is not transplantable into C++.  They each have their own strengths and shortcomings.  Trying to make C++ into being C#-like will be a Quixotic and futile exercise.

Comment: @Eljay

C# is better than C++ in readability, and in many other aspects including CG.

C++ **can** be written to run at least 10 times faster then C#, using 'usafe' and specifically tailored code.

The new C++ standard adopts many features that make C++ closer to higher level languages, like ranges, modules, 'safe' pointers, auto, etc.

There is nothing wrong in making C++ more readable..

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you **could** write `New` in C++ (warning, lightly tested)

```
  template <typename ... Args>
  struct NewHelper : public std::tuple<Args...>
  {
      using std::tuple<Args...>::tuple;

      template <typename R>
      operator R*()
      {
          return new_impl<R>(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof ... (Args)>{});
      }

      template <typename R, std::size_t... I>
      R* new_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>)
      {
          return new R(std::get<I>(static_cast<std::tuple<Args...>&>(*this))...);
      }
  };

  template <typename ... Args>
  auto New(Args&&... args)
  {
      return NewHelper<Args&&...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
```

Usage:

```
int* x;
x = New(42);

std::tuple<int&, std::string>* y;
y = New(*x, "Hello dangling reference");
```

Note, I said that you **could** write it, not that you **should** write it. This is highly counter-intuitive, anti-idiomatic C++ that should never be let near production code. It's fun to experiment with dangerous things, but fun is fun and work is work.

Comment: 1. Nice!

2. Actually answers the question I would give +3 only for that :)

3.  Fu*k idioms, long live chaos!

4. This definitely makes sense , especially if combined with these 'automatic' memory management thingies like unique_ptr. They are nice but you do have to match the constructor to the automatic manager. so definitely far beyond GC..

Comment: Actually, this New solution can make new objects that automatically fit the LHS. So  variants line uniqe_ptr, shared_ptr etc. can be created properly, and save repetitions. 

This is very much inline with the 'auto' idiom.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `safe_new` and `safe_delete` variant:
Which works but is not as aesthetes as I like

```
template<typename T>
void safe_delete(T **p) {
    if (*p == nullptr)
        return; // do not delete twice
    delete *p;
    *p = nullptr;
}

// call new but make sure to delete previous object
template<typename T, typename... Types>
void safe_new(T **p, Types... args) {
    if (*p != nullptr)
        delete p; // do not delete twice
    *p = new std::remove_pointer<std::remove_pointer<decltype(p)>::type>::type(args...);
}
```

Usage:

```
PagedHashMap<tuple<int, int, float>, Edge, boost::hash<tuple<int, int, float>> > *edge_map;
```

Call new with parameters but without explicit type:

```
safe_new(&edge_map, 2000000));
```

Please note this is not an exact answer - A better answer would be something like:

```
edge_map = new(20000);
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing safe about these functions.

Comment: LOL, there is nothing safe about C++, and the fact that std::weak_ptr exists proves this.

Answer (score 0):

First, the meanings of `new` in C++ and C# sharp are different. With C#, you would need to use `new` whenever you try to invoke a constructor. However with C++, you should only ever use `new` when you are trying to create an object whose lifetime is not limited by the scope it was created in. And even if you do need to manage object lifetime manually, you should consider using smart pointer instead.

So this code in C#:

```cs
List<int> ints = new(capacity: 100);
ints = new(capacity: 1000);
```

To rewrite it in C++, you really should not use `new`. Instead it should be written like:

```cpp
list<int> ints(100);
ints = list<int>(1000);
```

---

Now back to your problem, you were wondering at the second line, if you can reassign `ints` without typing out its type. While the type in this example is quite short, it could be quite verbose if the type was actually pretty long.

One way you can make it shorter is by creating a helper function that can create any object:

```cpp
template<typename ReturnType, typename ... Args>
ReturnType create(Args&& ... args)
{
    return ReturnType(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

What it does is simply forward all the arguments to the `ReturnType`'s constructor. You can then use it like:

```cpp
SOME_REALLY_REALLY_LONG_TYPE_NAME foo(100);
foo = create<decltype(foo)>(1000);
```

However, the `decltype(foo)` still feels verbose and redundant. To further shorten it, you can create another function that takes in `foo` as a reference, then do the `create` inside that function:

```cpp
template<typename Original, typename ... Args>
void reassign(Original& original, Args&& ... args)
{
    original = create<Original>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Now your code would become:

```cpp
SOME_REALLY_REALLY_LONG_TYPE_NAME foo(100);
reassign(foo, 1000);
```

Comment: Actually since they are pointers / pointers to pointer it would be 'new std::remove_pointer<std::remove_pointer<decltype(p)>::type>::type(args...); '
Which is barely readable.


The purpose of New(..) is to have less one reference to foo